# Rotate iOS 6 Compatible iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ios5, rotation, ios6

I'm working on an application (Xcode 4.5 iOS 6), it must be compatible for the devices that have installed software version, starting at 4.5 and default iPhone 5.

I know that the new iOS 6 changes came with the auto-rotate mode.

When you turn on your device "iPhone Simulator 6.0" application behaves normally but when I run the "iPhone Simulator 5.0" problems in the way of rotation.

I put in the code, along with new ways to rotate from iOS 6 and the old method (deprecated) to iOS 5.

So look for the rotate methods:

```
#pragma mark - Rotate Methods

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
   return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

#pragma mark - Rotate Methods iOS 5

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(interfaceOrientation))
    {
        [menuPortrait setHidden:NO];
        [menuLandscape setHidden:YES];
    }

    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(interfaceOrientation))
    {
        [menuPortrait setHidden:YES];
        [menuLandscape setHidden:NO];
    }
    return YES;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsPortrait(toInterfaceOrientation))
        {
            [self.menuLandscape setHidden:YES];
            [self.menuPortrait  setHidden:NO];
        }
        if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation))
        {
            [self.menuLandscape setHidden:NO];
            [self.menuPortrait setHidden:YES];
        }

    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}
```

Can you help me with some advice regarding this issue! Thanks in advance for your answers!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. I can't find anything anywhere. Where you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: I have a UISplitViewController as the root view and I added your iOS 5 methods to it and it now rotates properly. Your issue must be different than mine, but thanks.

Comment: I fix that problem and now my code is oky for iOS 6 & for iOS 5:#pragma mark - Rotate Methods

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
   return YES;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{    
    [super willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation duration:duration];
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I achieved it by subclassing all view controller like this:

//.h
    #import

```
@interface ITViewController : UIViewController

@end
```

//.m

```
#import "ITViewController.h"

@interface ITViewController ()

@end

@implementation ITViewController


- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

This force landscape orientation mode. You can update the content of both methods to comply to your desired behavior